# SQS FIFO like using RAbbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, fifo

is there a way to implement a FIFO queue based on key (like SQS message group ID) using RabbitMQ?
I have a system with multiple consumers that processes messages from the same group sequentially, this is done using SQS FIFO with MessageGroupId, but now I need to move to a RabbitMQ solution, but couldn't find out how.
I could use direct exchange, which enqueues using routing keys, but I need this to be dynamic, routing keys are based on content data.

Ex. I have 4 messages, A1, B1, A2, C1. Messages A1, B1, C1 should be processed by the consumers concurrently, but A2 should be processed only after A1.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

The AMQP protocol is so flexible that it allows you to create queues and bind them to the exchange with their own routing keys at runtime. So, what you are looking for for groups is indeed a dynamic queue per group and respective binding for the specific routing key.

Please, learn more about this feature in the official RabbitMQ docs:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-spring-amqp.html

Comment: I understood that I can bind a message key to a queue. So if I have two queues with binding keys A and B respectively, on receiving a message with key B, it would be routed to the second queue.
But if now I receive a message with key C, is a new message, I don't have a binding created for it yet. Where would the message be routed? Is there a way to make Rabbit choose a queue and make further messages with key C go to the same queue?
Thanks